# Can anyone assist me with this script?

Tags: unix

I'm having trouble with having the following command options -s and -f display what I need them to. The parameters are being recognized fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
defaultPath="/etc/passwd"
defaultShell="/bin/bash"
h_on=0
f_on=0
s_on=0

set -- $(getopt f:hs: "$@")  

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
   case "$1" in
      -f) f_on=1 ;;
      -h) h_on=1 ;;
      -s) s_on=1 ;;
      --) shift
          break ;;
   esac
   shift
done
   
if [ $h_on -eq 1 ]
then
   echo
   echo "Usage: shellsearch [OPTION...]"
   echo
   echo "-f FILE   Search in FILE. FILE must be formatted"
   echo "          like /etc/passwd."
   echo "          Defaults to /etc/passwd if not provided
   echo
   echo "-h        Display usage information."
   echo
   echo "-s SHELL  Display users with SHELL shell."
   echo "          SHELL must be in /etc/shells."
   echo "          Defaults to /bin/bash if not provided."
   exit 0
fi

if  [ $f_on -eq 1 ]
then
   echo "is $file readable?" '
fi

if [ $s_on -eq 1 ]
then 
   echo "is $shell a shell?"
fi
```

My wanted output is the following:

```
Input file: $file
Displaying users with shell $shell.
```

If anyone could help out/give advise that would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getopts` following examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash).

```
while getopts "f:hs:" opt
do
   case "${opt}" in
      f) f_on=1 ; file=${OPTARG};;
      h) h_on=1 ;;
      s) s_on=1 ; shell=${OPTARG};;
   esac
done
```

Furthermore, pay attention to quotes in this line

```
echo "          Defaults to /etc/passwd if not provided"
```

and in that line

```
echo "is $file readable?"
```